# How come fat people can't float?

Tags: body-fat, fat, water

I was wondering, if fat floats, how is it so that a fat guy with let's say 70% body fat is unable to float on water?

Comment: The context of this question does not fall under physical fitness.

Comment: This is off topic. Also, we know empirically that fat people have an easier time treading water. Also, 70% body fat is really, really high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, fat does float. There is a manswers episode about how girls with big natural boobs [float](http://www.spike.com/video-clips/ue7wng/manswers-do-bigger-ones-float).

Comment: Really? Are you serious?

Comment: lol yes, I provided the link to it, go watch it lol.